# Is correlation the best way to determine if variables will not add new information to a model?

Tags: correlation, feature-selection

When feeding two variables (features) to a model (could be linear regression, GBM, Random Forest), is (Pearson) correlation between the two variables the best way to determine that the second variable will not add new information to the model?

Comment: The question and the title ask different things. Could you disambiguate please?

Comment: Edited title. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is related to the "feature selection", also known as "model selection" in regression problems. First, we test the significance of individual coefficients $\beta_{i}$ that is correspondent to the feature $x_i$. This is a test of hypothesis, where the null and alternative hypotheses are as follows:

$H_0 : \beta_i = 0$

$H_1 : \beta_i \neq 0$

This is a t-test, for which the t-statistic is computed as follows:

$t_i = \frac{\hat{\beta}_i}{\sigma(\hat{\beta}_{i})},$

where $\hat{\beta}_i$ is your linear regression estimate and $\sigma(\hat{\beta}_{i})$ is the standard error related to that estimate.

At that stage, if multiple features ended up being "significant", a "multicollinearity" test is often handy to detect whether the features are significantly correlated with each other.

A common measure of collinearity is the variance inflation factor, which is a function of the coefficient of determination $R^2$. 
For more information about how to compute VIF's, take a look at the wikipage: 
[Variance inflation factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_inflation_factor)

You can also run some diagnostics on what people call "the hat matrix", which is $X^TX$, where $X$ is your $N*p$ design matrix such that $N$ is the number of observations and $p$ is the number of features. The inverse of that matrix ends up to be the correlation matrix of the regression coefficients. If a non-diagonal entry of that correlation matrix is significantly non-zero, then there is a good chance that two of your features are strongly correlated.

Another similar technique is to do a sequential model adequancy test, by "sequentially" adding variables one at a time and checking how much benefit, in terms of reduction in uncertainty, you get by adding one variable, given the other variables. This is an F-test, which is the essence of "forward and stepwise" model selection techniques.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, as stated in the question, I am asking if the inclusion of a second of two hypothetical variables is adding new information to the model. For example, a t-test on these variables in a linear regression model may reveal that variable 1 and variable 2 both have very significant contributions to the model. However, they may be nearly exactly the same, therefore the redundancy (and lack of new information added) is not captured by a t-test.

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly. I hope this might help.

Comment: So if I understand:  VIF: VIF runs regression using a variable as the response with a one vs. all approach. Since VIF is a transformation of R^2, and R^2 is the Pearson correlation squared, VIF is effectively Pearson correlation. Then you propose to compute the Pearson correlation of the variables outright, if I understand correctly. Then you propose comparing model accuracy by stepwise adding and removing variables and comparing model uncertainty. So, in short, Pearson correlation and step-wise variable addition, subtraction with comparison of fit are what you propose. Thanks for answer.